# Get error while I install: bower install bower ECMDERR,Tried all solutions

Tags: git, bower-install

Get error while I install:

```
bower install
```

> bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.i
>   u.edu:iucomm/bower-framework.git", exit code of #128 Host key verification faile
>   d. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the
>   correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have already run the command

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

on windows as well as used

```
{
    "proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
    "https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>"
}
```

in .bowerrc file.

I am able to find the setting 
[url "https://"] insteadOf = git:// in my .gitconfig file.
Moreover my .gitconfig file is in C://users//username
and my project folder is in C://

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to execute
>   "`git ls-remote --tags --heads git@github.iu.edu:iucomm/bower-framework.git`"

That means it does not use `git://` ([git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol)) but `(ssh://)git@` ([ssh protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol))

In that case, make sure to use a private key *without* passphrase.